# Using voice chat in Black Ops 2 on PC

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I recently got Call of Duty Black Ops 2 for my PC. I also have a gaming headset with microphone and was wondering if anybody could tell me how to use it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First go into Steam settings and see if your microphone is working.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/brHhKwa.png]

Click on the test microphone button and start speaking, the highlighted bars should start going up/down depending on the loudness of your voice.

[image]

Secondly set this up, unless you want microphone to turn on automatically when you speak:

[image]

Third step would be to go into game settings and check the microphone settings.

Regards,

Comment: I think he is asking how to activate voice within the game.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to chat in game. Also enable voice chat in the game settings and set the mic as the default communication device in sound settings on Windows. While in game, you need to press <kbd>Z</kbd> when speaking, like a hand radio.